# Expand the first layer/table in CSS

Tags: css, html, css-tables, layer

I want the first layer to expand to the whole screen when I apply my CSS properties. There are margins, left and right of the page.

What I want is *similar* to [this](http://www.bbc.co.uk).
The first layer is that one in black color.

How can I expand mine to the whole screen, then organize the content inside the remaining part?

Here is the CSS I have just proposed with my first layer:

```css
#main{  
    margin-top:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: You need to add more detail - such as your HTML. Pointing to a large complex page like the BBC and saying "you want this" isn't helpful in answering this question

Comment: I managed to solve it. Usually it was an issue of a table. When I add cellspacing=0 and cellpadding=0 the system get the image I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be more specific, a layer and a table are two very different things.  Also, the BBC site you referenced as well as most new websites use `<div>` tags to organize their html rather than tables.  If you could be more specific with some HTML examples you would get a lot more help.

If you have a heading `<div>` that has similar styling to the css you posted, then have a content wrapper `<div>` that you could set the width on it should do what you wanted.

Again, if you can be more specific, we can give more specific help.